# Formatting Timezone part of DateTime object in R

Tags: r, datetime, datetime-format, timezone-offset

Is there a way to extract the timezone or format the timezone part of a datetime object, in the form of, say "+530" instead of "IST" or "Asia/Kolkata"?

(Need this as it is the ISO 8601 format used in javascript)

Example:

```
as.POSIXct(1499773898,tz="Asia/Kolkata",origin="1970-01-01")
[1] "2017-07-11 17:21:38 IST"
```

Instead, I'd like to maybe specify the format argument in as.POSIXct, so that the output looks something like this:

```
[1] "2017-07-11 17:21:38 +530"
```

Or a function which can pull out the timezone offset in this manner:

```
timezone_offset("2017-07-11 17:21:38 IST")
[1] "+530"
```

Does lubridate or any other package have the capability to do this?

Comment: for writing to a file, check out `fwrite` function in the `data.table` package. by default it writes timestamps in ISO 8601

Answer (score 1):

You can do both with `format`, but note that result is character string, no longer POSIXct object.

```
x <- as.POSIXct(1499773898,tz="Asia/Kolkata",origin="1970-01-01")
```

"2017-07-11 17:21:38 IST"

e.g., Show timestamp in ISO 8601:

```
format(x, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
```

"2017-07-11T17:21:38+0530"

e.g., Show just offset from UTC:

```
format(x, "%z")
```

"+0530"

Note that for operations in R this has little consequence because all POSIXct objects are stored internally as numeric in UTC; seconds from 1970-01-01 00:00:00.

To write POSIXct timestamps in ISO 8601 to file, you can use `format` as described above or `fwrite` function in `data.table`, which does so by default (see `dateTimeAs` argument).

Comment: thank you so much! exactly what I needed. I needed the format so my output can be used by js code.

Comment: How can I write the offset in `+05:30` instead of `+0530`?
The `%z` writes it in `+0530` format.

Comment: @PeyM87 Starting with x in the answer, get the timestamp part as text (no timezone) `x1 <- format(x, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")` and timezone offset as text 
`x2 <- format(x, "%z")`, then insert the colon in the timezone part: `x2 <- paste0(substr(x2, 1, 3), ":", paste0(substr(x2, 4, 5)))`;  and paste it all together: `paste0(x1, x2)` should get you "2017-07-11T17:21:38+05:30"